# How to fit a big picture in a smaller space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a page that I'm designing, have created a small-circular NAV, on which I want to show a picture! But of course, the picture is quite big and when I'm using  it's going outside of the border and goes haywire!

How do i enter that bigger picture in that small space?

the circle's dimensions is 97-97

Thank you in advance!

### HTML

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="main_layout">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="horizontal_line"></div>
        <div id="jewellery1"></div>
        <div id="jewellery2"></div>
        <div id="jewellery3"></div>
        <div id="jewellery4"></div>
        <div id="jewellery5"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <header>
            <div id="header-top">
                    <div id="links">
                    <div id="f"></div>
                    <div id="g"></div>
                    <div id="t"></div>
                    <div id="pint"></div>
                    <div id="register">Register Now</div>
                    <div id="vertical_line"></div>
                    <div id="sign_in">Sign in</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </header>
            <div id="search_bar">

            </div>
    </div>  

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSs

```
.wrap {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;      
}
.main_layout {
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width:1280px;
    height:1024px;

}

#container1 {
    alignment-adjust:central;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    width:275px;
    height:1024px;
    float:left;
    background:#333333 no-repeat fixed;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

#logo {
    width:255px;
    height:245px;
    margin-left:28px;
    margin-top:15px;
    background:url(../Icons%20n%20pics/logo4.png) no-repeat;
}

#horizontal_line {
    width:90%;
    height:1px;
    background:#FFF no-repeat;
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top:0px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #999;
}

#jewellery1 {
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FFF;
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000; 
}

#jewellery1_pic {
    background:"http://www.ansjewelry.com/images/NEC211_des.jpg";
    background-size:cover;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}

#jewellery2 {
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FFF;
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000; 
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
}

#jewellery3 {
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FFF;
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000; 
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
}

#jewellery4 {
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FFF;
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000; 
}

#jewellery5 {
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FFF;
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:7px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
}

#container2 {
    alignment-adjust:central;
    margin-left:9px;
    margin-right:9px;
    width:985px;
    height:1024px;
    float:right;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF,#ece5da);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#FFF,#ece5da);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#FFF,#ece5da);
    background:linear-gradient(#FFF,#ece5da);
}

header {
    width:985px;
    height:310px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#header-top {
    width:985px;
    height:50px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    border-bottom:1px #000 outset;
}

#links {
    width:409px;
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:right;
}

#f {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:url(../Icons%20n%20pics/facebook.png);
    float:left;
}

#t {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:url(../Icons%20n%20pics/twitter.png);
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#g {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:url(../Icons%20n%20pics/google_plus.png);
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}


#pint {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    background:url(../Icons%20n%20pics/pinterest.png);
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#register {
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    font:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

#vertical_line {
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px;
    border-left:thin solid #000;
}

#sign_in {
    margin-top:12px;
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px;
    font:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

#slider {
    padding:0px;
    width:985px;
    height:199px;
    border-bottom:#000 1px outset;
}

#search_bar {
    width:985px;
    height:60px;
    margin-top:-49px;
    background:#39F;
}
```

Comment: don't css height and width fixed rather then auto help? and you'd better show code for people easier to help and future reading.

Comment: #jewellery1 {
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#FFF;
 width:97px;
 height:97px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:60px;
 box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;
 -ms-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
 -o-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000;  
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 6px 3px #000; 
}

Comment: ^^ this is the container for the picture!

The picture is http://www.ansjewelry.com/images/NEC211_des.jpg

Comment: You should put your code in the question, not in a comment. O_o

Comment: use `width;100%; height:auto;` in the css of the `img` element. Anyway, If it is possible, use a smaller image(width dimensions equal to those of the container) to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I have created a fiddle with your pasted code.**

You didn't quite have the right syntax for the background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/rnnj3ebc/

Try setting the image as the background image of the rounded element:

```
#nav {
    width:97px;
    height:97px;
    background:url('http://www.ansjewelry.com/images/NEC211_des.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:97px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qpm0a6mm/

Comment: No problems. In future try to include a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) with your question that way we can see your code and suggest fixes to any problems you are having.

Comment: Also make sure to flag this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the image's height and width to the dimensions you need to fit it in, using CSS. So, let's say that your image's `id` is `navPic`.

Then, you could write this CSS:

```
#navpic {    
    width: 97px; 
    height: 97px;
}
```

Of course, adjust the width and height, depending on whether you want the picture to fit all the way in or not.

Comment: How is it not working, can you show your current html and css?

Comment: <div id="container1">
     <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="horizontal_line"></div>
        <div id="jewellery1"><div id="jewellery1_pic"></div></div>
        <div id="jewellery2"></div>
        <div id="jewellery3"></div>
        <div id="jewellery4"></div>
        <div id="jewellery5"></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

use css property:

```
background-size:cover;
```